# matlab read file with question mark in each line

Tags: matlab

I have a `dat` file which contains `?` in every row.

e.g

```
1 ? 2008 3 31
2 ? 2013 2 01
```

How to read this file into matlab and then change the second column to numerical values?

Comment: The second column contains the question marks (`?`). How exactly do you expect it to be converted into numerical values?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your file format is as you presented, then you can do as follows:

```
% read data into C matrix,
% '?' will be read as number 63 in second column
fileID = fopen('data.txt');
C = fscanf(fileID, '%f %s %f %f %f', [5 inf])';
fclose(fileID);

C =

           1          63        2008           3          31
           2          63        2013           2           1
```

Change value of second column as you would do for normal matrix.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know where the question marks are located, I would recommend you to replace all of them with `NaN`. This way they can be read in as a number and you can still recognize them.

After doing this you can easily read in the file like this:

```
dlmread(`myData.dat`)
```

There are several ways to replace the question mark with `NaN`, easiest one for one time use is with a text editor and replace all.